# MySQL - Combining 2 Similar Tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables and I want to take the contents of table2 and add it to the end of table1 (eg: combine the 2 tables into 1). Would want the ID to continue to auto-increment.

Table 1:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `region1` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
   `region2` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
   `region3` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
   `zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `city` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
   `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5871647 ;
```

Table2:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extra` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `city` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
   `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=687421 ;
```

Have played with the following:

```
INSERT INTO world (country, city, latitude, longitude) 
VALUES SELECT country, city, latitude, longitude FROM extra;
```

thx

Comment: got any error or what you are expecting

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT country, city, latitude, longitude FROM extra' at line 2

Comment: I think values is not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try without values like below. [check this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO world (country, city, latitude, longitude) 
SELECT country, city, latitude, longitude FROM extra;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
INSERT INTO world (country, city, latitude, longitude) 
    SELECT country, city, latitude, longitude FROM extra;
```